# Joomla 3 custom Template

Tags: php, templates, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.1

I'd like to achieve the following content structure but no template I know fits it.

[image: Joomla Content Structure]

Can you advice me from what Template to start modifying? I thought of "Category Blog".
I'm currently planning to integrate the years by adding categories that contain categories with caption/description containig articles I want to be shown completely in this view.

In addition I'd feel grateful to you providing me sources to learn more about how to get the data I need (categories with description, articles with headline and content).

I until now just did CSS adjustments for Joomla based websites and therefore don't know that much about how to actually reviece data from the DB.
PHP and MySQL aren't a problem though.

A bit fuzzy maybe because I don't exactly know where to start but I'm hoping the best.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You might be best off looking into template overrides: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: Thank you. That prevented me from modifying the original files :) Do you know some good place do inform myself about how to get categories, articles, etc. from the database to fill the view with data?